# Building a 2 mile runway on a 1x1 mile island

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, lateral-thinking, open-ended

You have a `1-mile long` x `1-mile wide` island.

When taking off from a flat runway, a plane requires a runway of minimum length 2 miles in order for takeoff to be physically possible, achieving minimum takeoff speed at the very end of the runway.

Remaining within the boundaries of the island, what shape and size do you build a runway to make it physically possible for the plane to take off?

The island is on the planet Earth and the usual laws of physics apply. No other form of transport is available. The plane cannot take off from water or perform any part of its takeoff run on water. Flight safety legislation does not apply.

---

See also [Aviation.SE: Best answer for a puzzle from aeronautical point of view](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13385/best-answer-for-a-puzzle-from-aeronautical-point-of-view)

Comment: Since you got there with [the infinite rope](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/how-to-get-to-an-island-with-a-tree-in-the-middle-if-all-you-have-is-rope) you could just... oops, wrong Google interview question.

Comment: @GOTO0 No, you're supposed to jump out of the blender.

Comment: What I do is point out that there's no way such a tiny island requires such a long runway. The smaller Boeing 737 models can take off from a runway less than a mile long and it's not like you need to be landing Jumbos at your resort.

Comment: Build a space elevator instead.

Comment: Are we talking real-world airplanes, or spherical-cow airplanes?

Comment: This is underspecified.  What shapes is the runway allowed to have?

Comment: Build a dock that extends past the shore. I feel like this puzzle is too vague to be interesting.

Comment: Must check out the Juancho E. Yrausquin Airport, Island of Saba, 1200' runway sea to sea.  tourist based economy.  A great flight experience.

Comment: @PeterKämpf has posted [one possible solution on Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13388/4067).

Comment: I have designed an ingenious solution involving the use of a giant treadmill which this comment is too short to contain.

Comment: @AdamDavis A treadmill would have almost no effect because planes are powered by the action of their engines against the air, not by the action of their wheels against the ground. (And they take off because of their speed relative to the air, not to the ground.) A backwards-moving treadmill would probably generate a slight (helpful) headwind by dragging air with it; a forwards-moving treadmill would propel the plane forwards slightly because of friction in its wheel bearings but also create a slight (unhelpful) tailwind. I doubt either case would help a lot.

Comment: @DavidRicherby ;)

Comment: I have two words for you, Aircraft carrier. Park one next to the island and you're golden. Or if it has to be within the confines of the island, simply put it down on the island and you'll have plenty of room to spare. It's a well tested technology with aircrafts capable of personnel transport already available. Otherwise build a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globe_of_death sized for aircraft, nothing was said about landing.

Comment: I would like to answer, but apparently I don't have sufficient reputation. I would build a runway on an incline - imagine a triangle with the hypotenuse serving as the incline - and the airplane could descend the incline. If the length of the runway needs to be 2 miles long and the island is 1 mile squared then the incline will be 2 miles, the side sitting on the island will be 1 mile long, and the remaining side will be the sq. root of 3. or approximately 1.7321 miles. I think this fits because the question only states that the airplane needs to PHYSICALLY be able to take off.

Comment: Furthermore, the question states that the plane needs 2 miles on a FLAT runway. I assume this implies that an inclined runway could be shorter.

Comment: This question got 5k views in 2 days? Impressive!

Comment: @leoll2 That's nothing; [this question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9979/brooklyn-99-riddle-weighing-islanders) was closed as a duplicate within a few hours but got 50k views within a few days!

Comment: And here we have a reminder of how HNQ almost destroyed puzzling.SE.

Comment: Easy. The runway doesn't need to be 2 miles long. Ground effect. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_effect_%28aerodynamics%29

Comment: Use different aircraft ;) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pweY5y5eRI

Comment: I Appreciate all answers given by all genius members :)

Comment: Forget the runway.  Use a threadmill.  ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is simple: Build an elevated two mile long runway and anchor all of its supports on the island land.

Everything that touches the ground is within the boundaries of the island. Since we are talking about a 3D structure and the island boundaries is something only valid on 2D. So, this is arguably valid since there is no clear definition of island boundary in airspace.

[image: Elevated runway]

Lets see if it passes all the requirements:

- The runway must be flat. - $\color{green}{\text{OK}}$
- The runway must be at least 2 miles long. - $\color{green}{\text{OK}}$
- You should remain within the boundaries of the island. - $\color{orange}{\text{I am abusing this, but it passes as explained above}}$
- The island is on planet Earth. - $\color{green}{\text{OK}}$
- Usual laws of physics applies. - $\color{green}{\text{OK}}$
- No other form of transport. - $\color{green}{\text{OK}}$
- The plane cannot take off from water or perform any part of its takeoff run on water. - $\color{green}{\text{It is not on water, it is on over-water airspace, so it's OK}}$
- Flight safety legislation does not apply. - $\color{green}{\text{OK}}$

About the picture, I know that it would be easier to build it along the diagonal, but this way it is more beautiful and the island size and shape almost do not matter in this answer.

Comment: "Everything that touches the ground is within the boundaries of the island." Ah, yes. The "I'm not touching you!" provision of international law.

Comment: That's it. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: you could do the same but over the diagonal, and make it more robust ;)

Comment: @Victor Stafusa Great Answer.. I would build the bridge diagonally instead of the one shown in the diagram.

Answer (score 45):

Build two straight runways side to side, 1 mile long each.

Then, put a portal-conducting surface at the end of the first runway and another one at the beginning of the second one. Finally, use your portal gun to place a yellow portal on one of those surfaces and a blue portal in the other one.

[image: Island 3D rendering]

Comment: @randal'thor Edited to add an image. What do you think about that? :D

Comment: Even cooler! I wonder if you'll get as many upvotes as Richard did with his [black hole](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/4345/5373)?

Comment: This is clearly the way to go.

Comment: Now you're thinking with portals!

Comment: +1 for realistic physics: this is one of the few answers that doesn't require aircraft to turn impossible corners or go up impossibly steep hills on their take-off roll.

Comment: You are wasting material; just have a portal at the beginning and the end of the runway, and you'll have an infinite long runway. Start in the middle and during the third lap you'll take off and not hit the wall with the portal.

Comment: @Sumurai8 is right, and what's more the runway needn't be a mile long - it only needs to be a few times longer than the plane itself, just enough length for the to exit wormhole 1 at flight speed then rotate and fly above the entrance to wormhole 2.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Realistic physics?! :-o

Comment: -1 for not using realistic physics (portals).

Comment: In fact, forget the planes. Just have a portal to each place planes go to, if answers are allowed to use portals.

Comment: @randal'thor It was a joke. Please engage your humor sensor.

Comment: @immibis this would imply visiting the destination in the first place…

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer I realised it was a joke. So was my comment. Please engage *your* humour sensor.

Comment: Or simply forget about the stupid plane and use a Nimbus 2000 broomstick. Easy to take off, not runway needed.

Comment: @randal'thor Ah, my mistake. It didn't read comically.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer No worries! :-) These things can come across the wrong way in writing, I know.

Comment: Yeah, I outscored my own other answer to get the populist golden badge. LOL

Answer (score 28):

[image]

Question says nothing about landing.

Comment: "The island is on the planet Earth and the usual laws of physics apply." Either you have really strong engines, or that crane is absurdly tall.

Comment: @mdc32 -  What do the engines have to do with anything?  You could launch a glider like this.  Wing load during the dive is the limiting factor here.

Comment: Creative, although in some ways just a variation on @leoll2's catapult idea. [WP: Assisted takeoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_take-off)

Comment: @SteveV, the power of the engines makes a difference to the necessary crane-height. A gilder would require a higher crane than a powered aircraft, because the powered aircraft's engines allow it to achieve greater speed in the same vertical drop, although I agree that in either case you're screwed if the wings fall off.

Comment: If you spin the crane up you wouldn't have to worry about engine power :)

Answer (score 26):

You need to:

> build a runway that goes diagonally through the island and is sqrt(2) miles higher in one corner than it's diagonally opposite corner.

Why?

> The diagonal of the island is sqrt(2). You need a straight line of length 2, so we add in the third dimension. Using a height of sqrt(2), we get a hypotenuse of length exactly 2 miles.

Bonus:

> Add additional height to both sides so that the plane does no hit the water at the end of the runway.

More boni inspired by the coments:

> Make the runway curved or make a horizontal segment at the very end of the runway (in that case we'll need a the other segment to be a bit steeper).

Finally:

> Use a [floatplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floatplane).

Comment: This sort of defeats the purpose of a runway, though, since your plane will either be climbing up the runway which means it won't have enough speed to take off, or climbing down the runway which means it won't have enough angle to avoid hitting the ground.

Comment: You'd have to add quite a lot of height in order to be able to counteract a 45° downward slope.

Comment: You don't even need a float plane. The smaller Boeing 737 models can take off in less than a mile and an island of this size surely can't need planes bigger than that.

Comment: @JoeZ. Runways with a gradient exist in the real world (although possibly not as strong as this one). I think planes typically land climbing up and take off going down, not the other way around.

Comment: @Relaxed This is definitely the case in Lukla (Nepal - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_NFd9nsjEw ) and in La Paz (Bolivia). I have landed and taken off from both and they can be fairly 'exciting'.

Comment: @Relaxed Yes, but my point is that a gradient of 1:1 seems like a tad much, don't you think?

Comment: @JoeZ. Certainly but it's a puzzle after all. And your earlier comment seemed to focus on the speed when climbing up or the angle when approaching downward, which kind of obscured the point because that's not how a sloped runway, real of fictional, would be used.

Comment: @Relaxed This may be a puzzle, but it's not "build a 2-mile strip," it's "build a 2-mile *runway*". A 100% gradient fails to be a runway (as "planes can use it" is a necessary component of that).

Comment: @cpast Maybe, but it still has very little to do with whether climbing up a slope prevents plane from taking off, which has been my point all along. The comment that started all this did not even object to the steepness of the gradient, just the idea of a sloped runway.

Comment: Sorry, I did in fact mean that I objected to a runway that was sloped that much, not just one that was sloped at all.

Comment: @JoeZ But if the runway has a curved profile at the bottom so it's flat to begin with and then the gradient increases, then that doesn't just solve the problem, it's actually more efficient than a normal runway. Planes take off downslope (getting a speed boost as they do) and land upslope (converting speed into height as they slow down). Only problem is that planes must take off at the very end of the runway, which makes an aborted takeoff impossible. Think of a ski jump.

Comment: @JoeZ. Well the runway can be curved or it can "straighten-out" at the very end.

Comment: Related research: [Aircraft Operations From Runways With Inclined Ramps (Ski-Jump)](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a237265.pdf)

Comment: I've amended the problem definition so that the runway doesn't have to be 2 miles long, but rather the plane has to be going at a viable flight speed given that it takes 2 miles of flat runway to achieve a viable flight speed. So a 'ski jump' runway can actually be a bit shorter.

Comment: Peter Kämpf says [on Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13388/4067), " For aircraft which need a 2 miles long level runway, a 1 mile long one with a 15% slope at its end will do just fine. ... You do not even need to run it diagonally across the island."

Comment: I'll admit that a curved runway would solve the takeoff problem.

Answer (score 20):

Build a runway that goes along one side of the island, turns in a *banked* quarter circle with a small but sufficiently large radius, and then goes along the adjacent side. If it were horizontal the length would be slightly less than 2 miles, so raise it at the end where the aeroplane will be stationary. The key word is *banked*.

Comment: Excellent. This would be cheaper than a 'ski jump' runway because much smaller amount of earthworks involved. Would need a lot of skill to stay on the runway in the event of an aborted takeoff (because plane would be going at a different speed than the banking was designed for so couldn't just go straight down the centre-line), but pilots would probably enjoy it. Sorts the men from the boys.

Comment: @raptortech97 - the question specifically states "Flight safety legislation does not apply.".

Answer (score 15):

> You have a `1 mile long` x `1 mile wide` private island that you wish to
>   turn into a resort. A plane requires a 2-miles long runway to take
>   off. What do you do?

- Have tourists arrive by boat or helicopter.
- Build a [floating airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_airport).
- [Artificially extend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_island) the island's area.
- Use [seaplanes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seaplane), which can take off or land on water.

Answer (score 15):

Alternate answer:

The question says the plane needs a 2 mile runway *to take off*, but says nothing about landing. So  have people fly in, land on a short runway, then dump the plane in the ocean to make room for the next one. If people insist on leaving, they can swim for it.

Comment: Rofl ... I can see this question is going to be the new http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/how-to-get-to-an-island-with-a-tree-in-the-middle-if-all-you-have-is-rope

Comment: Generally speaking, planes take more runway to land than to take off.

Comment: Tuck and roll! You'll be fine!

Comment: @reptortech97 Not necessarily. Most planes I've flown are capable of stopping shorter than taking off. Especially if they have more than just brakes to help. The bigger question is, how do you define a takeoff? Is it off the ground or able to climb away from the surface? :-)

Comment: @Shawn: *all* aircraft are capable of stopping in a shorter distance than is required for takeoff. No brakes, thrust reversers, or etc required... :->

Comment: @Duncan: duck and cover? :-)

Comment: @Bob Jarvis :-) That was kinda my point in my response.

Answer (score 11):

Your longest horizontal path on the island is $\sqrt{2}$ miles (approx 1.4 miles), so there's no straight, horizontal solution on the island proper. (That is, what looks like the intended approach seems to have no valid answer.)

Use alternate transport (e.g. seaplane) or start a land reclamation project. Or make arrangements with a neighbouring island that happens to be 2 miles long :) .

Comment: I thought to make runway on water. actually its an interview question I found on Google but don't know the answer.

Comment: Yup, I considered that also, but it's effectively land reclamation.

Comment: Interview questions have had some very creative solutions on this site and elsewhere - I'm looking forward to what others come up with.

Comment: yes you are right. lets see who will give best solution.

Answer (score 9):

> Build a giant bowl and let the plane land initially at the top (albeit sideways). The centripetal force will keep the plane stuck to the inclined surface until it can dissipate enough speed doing loops around the bowl to settle at the bottom.
>
> Aircraft normally experience a max of around 2g during takeoff/landing so that's a nice benchmark to shoot for. Going to neglect gravity itself here since optimizing the roll angle to account for what a 747 could actually handle would take a bit of digging (especially the rudder as I doubt a jetliner could fly at 90 deg roll sustainably). With those simplifications though, a = (v^2)/r ---> r = 83^2/(9.81*2) = 354 meters. So with roughly half a mile of square space, you could land a 747 in your bowl. So long as the plane doesn't fall to pieces.
>
> All that being said, taking off is probably even harder since you now have to overcome that centripetal force to break away from the bowl...

EDIT:
Could also double as amusement park ride.

Comment: I like this answer very much, although I have a few concerns about practicality. An airliner [can do a barrel roll](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/1744606/) but I'm not confident that it can land while sideways. Perhaps we should ask on Aviation.SE?

Comment: Psh... ok what if it didn't land at all? You could just pack everyone into some kind of glorified hamster ball and release them into the edge of the bowl as the pilot makes a pass. That way the ball does a couple laps around the bowl before settling to the bottom.

Comment: I suppose that makes getting off the island a little more problematic though. Leaving the island does seem to be the crux of this solution.

Comment: Coming over here from Aviation.SE, this idea is probably the best (apart from the extensions, which is kind of cheating!). I quickly did some maths, and I don't think you can make a bowl that is shallow enough for planes to land but round enough to make 2 miles of length. I don't think landing in a roll would work to well, especially since you are neglecting the lift the wings produce when you are talking about 2Gs keeping the plane on the "ground". Straight in landings could work, as well as takeoffs, where the bowl could be used as a kind of a velocity head.

Comment: And here are some answers from an aeronautical point of view: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13385/5592

Comment: Thanks for link to the aviation.se version of this! I realize this solution involves putting the plane into what's probably the most unstable position in can be and then trying to land in that position, so obviously not for the faint of heart ;) As a side note, would you mind pointing me in the direction you took to calculate the bowl incline? I'd be interested to know how you approached that since I have basically zero experience in aircraft aerodynamics :)

Comment: [An early prototype](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_igDAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA17&dq=popular%20science%20june%201919&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Oh my gosh, I love it @AE ! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 6):

There are several solution:

1. [**Aircraft Catapult**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_catapult)
2. Build an **artificial hill** on the corner of the island so that you can build a downhill runway, which can be longer than 2 miles if the hill is high enough.
3. Build a **circular runway** (max length is π) and let the airplane run on the track until it can take off.

Comment: Your circular runway has the length: 2$\pi$r = $\pi$ > 2 miles when r=1/2. You could also use 2 straight sides of the square connected by a curved piece. However, all runways I know are straight.

Comment: I made a mistake, the max length of the circular runway is π (not π/2). I chose a circle as shape because it isn't much different from a straight line when the object moving on it is much smaller than radius. The example is earth's surface, it's spherical (ok, I know it isn't), but you see it flat when you walk.

Comment: It doesn't work, but http://www.endlessrunway-project.eu/

Comment: Why not? The runway in your link has a 3 km diameter, which isn't much different from the 1,6 km of this problem. Also, I don't think that you want a Boeing 747 land on this little island, a small aircraft is very agile and has enough turn rate to take off from a circular runway.

Comment: Ah, its the idea itself that doesn't work. Landing planes on a runway like that wouldn't work and by the time the runway is big enough for it to work it becomes pointless. The issue wasn't the applicability. http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1909/1368

Comment: "The runway in your link has a 3 km diameter, which isn't much different from the 1,6 km of this problem." It's a factor of two! That's a huge difference. And I'm not sure where you got the idea that small aircraft can take off on a corner.

Comment: Well, we're talking about a small aircraft, not a DC-10. You may say that wings would touch the ground when you steer in a circular runway: wrong, because you just need the rudder, which is more than enough to turn.

Comment: +1 for the catapult, although actually if it takes a 2 mile flat runway to take off then we're talking about a really large aircraft.

Comment: @Lawrence: [This one isn't!](https://www.airnav.com/airport/S90)

Comment: @Sean That would make it tricky to accelerate for takeoff.

Answer (score 5):

Build a runway:

> That starts in one corner of the island, goes straight for half a mile, then makes a half circle turn until it hits the other side of the island, then continues straight for half a mile. The half circle will have a circumference of 1/2 * 2pi*r, where r = 1/2.

This gives it a length of:

> 1/2 + 1/2 * 2*pi*1/2 + 1/2 = 1 + pi/2. This is greater than 2 (about 2.57), so it gives you some leeway.

It also has these advantages:

> Leaving most of the space in the middle for the resort.

and

> Having straightaways at the beginning/end of the runway for when the plane has the most speed (takeoff and landing) and can't turn as quickly.

You better hope:

> That the wind is blowing in the right direction, though.

Comment: If your runway has a 180-degree corner in it, it isn't a runway. Having the corner in the middle isn't an advantage: it's the worst possible place because it minimizes the length of the longest straight section and only the straight section is useful.

Comment: Well, having a 1 mile by 1 mile island where you need to build a 2 mile runway also isn't an advantage. I'm going with most of this situation being unrealistic, so the minor issue of having a curved runway is something I'm willing to work with.

Comment: The situation is unrealistic in the sense that it's a bad business decision; your answer is unrealistic in that it's physically impossible. That's a rather different level of unrealism.

Comment: Bank the runway where it curves.

Answer (score 5):

Mobius Landing Strip FTW! :)

That or cut the island into fractions and stick it to itself.

Also you could have an extending drawbridge type runway that retracts or one that has buoys to float with in the water.

My favorite for the fancy resort factor would be a runway that is in a completely glass tube that goes underwater and takes you to the under ground grand entryway of the resort

Comment: Or you can make it a James Bond/ Secret Agent themed resort where people have to parachute in :)

Answer (score 4):

If I was making a resort on such a tiny island, there's no way in the universe that I'd put a runway on it. The space it would take up would ruin the resort atmosphere of the island. That land would be needed to make the resort.

Instead,

> require people to come by boat or, as DMG said, by floatplane

Answer (score 4):

An entertaining option:

Leave the runway flat and level at length 1 mile (or sqrt(2) miles if you like) and use [Rocket-Assisted Takeoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JATO).

> JATO (acronym for jet-assisted take off), is a type of assisted take-off for helping overloaded aircraft into the air by providing additional thrust in the form of small rockets. The term JATO is used interchangeably with the (more specific) term RATO, for Rocket-Assisted Take Off (or, in RAF parlance, RATOG for Rocket-Assisted Take Off Gear).

Like this:

[image: Hawker Hurricane launched from CAM ship c1941.jpg]

[image: C-130T Hercules Blue Angels.jpg]

[image: Boeing B-47B rocket-assisted take off on April 15, 1954 061024-F-1234S-011.jpg]

> As the take-off thrust of jet engines has grown, JATO has fallen from favor. It is still used, however, when heavily-laden aircraft need to take off from ***short runways*** or when operating in "Hot and high" conditions.

Rather surprisingly, rocket-assisted takeoff is actually flight-certified for the Boeing 727:

> JATO:
>   6 Aerojet 15KS-1000-A1 thrust augmentation units, approved for use with Pratt and Whitney JT8D-11, JT8D-15, JT8D-15A, and JT8D-17, JT8D-17A Turbofans with 15° flaps.

[A3WE
The Boeing Company
Model - 727 - 200](http://www.boeing-727.com/Data/type%20cert/typecert200ser.html)

Comment: Apparently, Mexicana experimented with fitting JATO to their 727s as a backup in case there was an engine failure during take-off at a high-altitude airport on a hot day (e.g., Mexico City). There's a photo of a test run about three-quarters of the way down [this page](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/print.main?id=3004497). Discussion there says it was never used on a passenger flight.

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly I don't see the obvious answer:

> Use a different plane, for goodness sake! One that can actually take off and land in 1.4 miles.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the problem to fitting a 2-mile length into a length of 1.414 miles. Let's say we don't want any bends. How do we do it? Use rollers! Say each roller has a diameter of 1 yard. Make them of a suitable material and construct the holding mechanism in such a way that when the plane travels 1 yard relative to the island its wheels have been in contact with the roller for 1.414 yards.

Comment: This doesn't work. To take off, aircraft need speed relative to the air, not to the ground. It's not that you need to travel for two miles before take-off: it's that it takes two miles to reach sufficient airspeed to take off. (Except that it takes way less than that, unless you're in a very, very large plane.)

Comment: It also doesn't work because planes are powered by the action of their engines against the air, not by their wheels on the ground. If you effectively moved the ground backwards under the plane, it would just make its wheels rotate faster, and slow the plane very slightly because of increased friction in its wheel bearings.

Comment: @DavidRicherby so giant air blowers could help?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Very much so, if they created a headwind. That's why planes take off into the wind wherever possible.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Many thanks for this! I should have recalled that when launching a kite after laying its string on the ground, you need to stand with your back to the wind, and if necessary run against the wind not away from it!

Answer (score 2):

You could

> dig the runway parallel to one of the sides of 1 x 1 island such that the first 0.5 mile of the runway has an angle of declination of 60 degrees and the next half has an angle of inclination of 60 degrees. The total length of the runway will be 2 miles then.

[image]

Comment: Diagram not to scale. The angles you've marked as 60deg are closer to 30! In any case, this wouldn't work. No commercial plane can accelerate to take-off speed while going up a 60-degree slope.

Comment: Obviously the diagram is not to scale. I'm hoping in future they can invent technologies that allow for an aircraft to take-off a 60 degree slope.

Answer (score 1):

If the runway is approximately straight and level, as it should be for it to be "physically possible for the plane to take off," then there is no way to fit a 2-mile-long island on a 1-mile square island. Especially if you consider that a plane requiring a *minimum* of two miles to take off should probably have a runway that is *longer* than two miles, in case there are any sub-optimal conditions for takeoff.

So, how can we build such a runway while "remaining within the boundaries of the island"? Simple. **Expand the island.** Use [land reclamation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_reclamation) to build up the shores, so eventually the island gets bigger, and then build a runway on it. Some commenters have observed that there isn't much use for a one-square-mile island, so this fixes that problem by giving you more usable space, too.

Also, this is much less far-fetched than some of the other proposed constructions. In fact, the [airport in Genoa, Italy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genoa_Cristoforo_Colombo_Airport) is built on an artificial peninsula of reclaimed land, proving the feasability of this idea.

Comment: "If the runway is approximately [...] level, as it should be for it to be 'physically possible for the plane to take off,'" Tell that to people who've flown to [Courchevel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courchevel_Altiport).

Comment: @DavidRicherby For one thing, the 18.6% grade there is a lot less than the 100% grade required to build a flat runway on the existing island. Also, if you achieve "minimum takeoff speed at the very end of the runway" and are traveling downward at that point... I don't think you're going to be taking off.

Comment: That's why you put a flat bit (or even a 'ski jump' upwards ramp) at the bottom, going into a gradual curve upwards. See dmg's answer (above) and its comments or http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13388/4067

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several approaches:
1. If you must use planes, you can extend the island out to meet the requirement.
2. You can use `seaplanes/floatplanes`, so there's no need for runway, since the ocean is your runway.
3. You can use `vtols`, so you just need a flat area large enough to fit your plane.

Comment: The "requirement" for a two-mile runway is misleading. The smaller models of Boeing 737 can take off in under a mile and an island of this size isn't going to require planes even that big. So there's no need for float planes or VTOLs (though, in reality, float planes might be a good option, since they avoid paving over large amounts of your beautiful island).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rotating platform at the end of the runway (on a corner of the island).
Thus when the plane enters onto the circular platform, it rotates by 180 degrees while your plane continues where it came from.

Comment: You're proposing to turn the plane through 180 degrees in the middle of its take-off run? Conservation of momentum isn't going to let that happen.

Comment: Depends. You can put 2 more wheels at the edges of the wings and put 2  rocket assisted engines on the nose of the plane positioned at an angle of 90 degrees relative to the aircraft. This should distribute the angular momentuum and ensure that it works. Clearly, much also depends on the skill of the pilots.

Comment: If you're going to put rockets on your plane, just put them pointing backwards to generate more thrust so the aircraft can take off from a much shorter runway, without needing infeasible corners. It's called JATO. [It's an actual thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JATO).

Comment: JATO rockets can be used to take-off only, but for landing that can't be used. With the help of the mobile platform you would have several alternatives. The first solution is to use the engines deflectors so as to help airplane to rotate (rather than to stop as normally used);

Comment: if the previous was not enough, as mentioned before, may be implemented only two rockets side (instead of several more if used for the primary thrust) to make it take-off or land, or create a flow channel that uses the main turbines (as it happens with the deflectors) but leading the flow to the front of the plane and it does get out of side.

Comment: In both situations, from the point of view of passengers safety would be better than sticking a dozen JATO near the main engines (explosions, fires, etc.). In fact, no more in used since at least the Cold War thanks to safer alternatives (see catapults on aircraft carriers for fighters).

Comment: Landing requires much less runway than take-off because the plane is much lighter when landing: up to 40% of the take-off weight is fuel. Beyond that, I don't know why you've got it into your head that an existing technology that is proven to work (JATO) is *more* dangerous than something that you just made up (turning a corner with sideways-acting rockets). And you still haven't dealt with the conservation of momentum issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this runway should be a shallow "skateboard ramp" design. Lizard Island on the Great Barrier Reef is a good example. Aircraft need to be able to taxi uphill at both ends. Such a perfect half tube would be 2.22 miles. So I probably would increase the radius a tad. Or implement a tractor tow system.

Answer (score 0):

Go down one edge of the island for .9 miles then turn and go along the diagonal of the island. Which gives a length >2.17 miles.

Comment: This works for tron, why not planes?

Answer (score 0):

Build a runway like this
where the height of the run way is sqrt(3) m high. Or go through the digonal in that case you only need height of sqrt(2)m

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to go with an Euler spiral ([Wikipedia explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral))

While indeed it becomes increasingly difficult to turn at higher speeds, this has the benefit that the curvature of the spiral would decrease with the increasing speed. Seems like a two mile length would easily be doable, IF:

1) The motors thrust can be 'unequal', to actually perform said turns

2) The tires don't blow out

3) You have little to no 'use' for the island. The shape really messes up what functionality the island can have.

Answer (score -2):

It is a circular runway that is inscribed within the 1 mile x 1 mile square with an approach tangent to the circle.

Comment: Never seen an aircraft land on a circular runway...

Comment: Never seen a run way 2 miles long! :).... Never mind, just checked and they exist.

Comment: that's true actually... ahahah

Comment: @GhostKoi 2 miles is 10,560 feet. Major international airports tend to have runways in the 8,000-13,000ft range.

Comment: I know... that's why I edited my comment. It was still a funny response though

Answer (score -2):

**How advanced are we in technology?**

Just build a treadmill-like runway in a straight line across the Island (1 mile long) with the plane going against the direction it rotates.  The plane pick up the speed required to takeoff, then you stop the treadmill runway.

Flight safety legislation really does not apply here*

Comment: Since the airplane is not powered by traction with the runway, a treadmill will not significantly affect the distance required to take off.

Comment: Oh ok, I was thinking the traction might give a boost to the initial speed which result in a much shorter runway is required.

Comment: @KSmarts: Even if the plane doesn't gain enough speed to become airborne on the treadmill, couldn't it gain some tire-rotating speed, so then when it hits the post-treadmill section of the runway, it's like hitting the ground running...  and doesn't need as much runway to build up the initial speed?