# Island Riddle. - How would you approach this and what is your mentality?

Tags: logical-deduction, weighing

There are 12 people on an island. 11 of the 12 people weigh the exact same. However one of them weighs different(more or less you don't know). You have a seesaw. You can only use the seesaw 3 times. Find the different person!

Comment: Welcome to [puzzling.se]! Same puzzle, different setting: [Twelve balls and a scale](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/183/twelve-balls-and-a-scale)